# package not found issue when i create conda with environment.yaml

Tags: server, pytorch, nlp, conda, torchvision

this error raised up...

please help me

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - torchvision==0.5.0=py36_cu100
  - pytorch==1.4.0=py3.6_cuda10.0.130_cudnn7.6.3_0
```

when I run `conda env create --file environment.yaml`

and this is my yaml file.
with it I can't create conda environment, because of that error

```
name: torch1.4
channels:
  - anaconda
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - _pytorch_select=0.1=cpu_0
  - attrs=19.3.0=py_0
  - backcall=0.1.0=py_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - catalogue=1.0.0=py_0
  - cffi=1.13.2=py36h8022711_0
  - cudatoolkit=10.0.130=0
  - cymem=2.0.3=py36he1b5a44_0
  - cython-blis=0.4.1=py36h516909a_0
  - decorator=4.4.2=py_0
  - freetype=2.9.1=h8a8886c_1
  - importlib_metadata=1.5.0=py36_0
  - intel-openmp=2020.0=166
  - ipdb=0.12.3=py_0
  - ipython=7.13.0=py36h5ca1d4c_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py_1
  - jedi=0.16.0=py36_0
  - jpeg=9b=h024ee3a_2
  - jsonschema=3.2.0=py36_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.33.1=h53a641e_7
  - libedit=3.1.20181209=hc058e9b_0
  - libffi=3.2.1=hd88cf55_4
  - libgcc-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libgfortran-ng=7.3.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libpng=1.6.37=hbc83047_0
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libtiff=4.1.0=h2733197_0
  - mkl=2020.0=166
  - mkl-service=2.3.0=py36he904b0f_0
  - mkl_fft=1.0.10=py36_0
  - mkl_random=1.0.2=py36_0
  - murmurhash=1.0.0=py36he1b5a44_0
  - ncurses=6.2=he6710b0_0
  - ninja=1.10.0=hc9558a2_0
  - numpy=1.18.1=py36h4f9e942_0
  - numpy-base=1.18.1=py36hde5b4d6_1
  - olefile=0.46=py_0
  - openssl=1.1.1f=h7b6447c_0
  - pandas=1.0.3=py36h0573a6f_0
  - parso=0.6.2=py_0
  - patsy=0.5.1=py36_0
  - pexpect=4.8.0=py36_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=py36_1000
  - pillow=6.1.0=py36h34e0f95_0
  - pip=20.0.2=py_2
  - plac=0.9.6=py_1
  - preshed=3.0.2=py36he1b5a44_1
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.3=py_0
  - ptyprocess=0.6.0=py_1001
  - pycparser=2.19=py_0
  - pygments=2.5.2=py_0
  - pyrsistent=0.15.7=py36h516909a_0
  - python=3.6.10=h0371630_0
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
  - pytorch=1.4.0=py3.6_cuda10.0.130_cudnn7.6.3_0
  - pytz=2019.3=py_0
  - readline=7.0=h7b6447c_5
  - scipy=1.1.0=py36hfa4b5c9_1
  - setuptools=45.2.0=py36_0
  - six=1.14.0=py36_0
  - spacy=2.2.3=py36hc9558a2_0
  - sqlite=3.31.1=h7b6447c_0
  - srsly=1.0.0=py36he1b5a44_0
  - statsmodels=0.11.0=py36h7b6447c_0
  - thinc=7.3.0=py36hc9558a2_0
  - tk=8.6.8=hbc83047_0
  - torchtext=0.5.0=py_1
  - torchvision=0.5.0=py36_cu100
  - tqdm=4.42.1=py_0
  - traitlets=4.3.3=py36_0
  - wasabi=0.6.0=py_0
  - wcwidth=0.1.8=py_0
  - wheel=0.34.2=py_1
  - xz=5.2.4=h14c3975_4
  - zipp=3.1.0=py_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - zstd=1.3.7=h0b5b093_0
  - pip:
    - ConfigArgParse-1.5.3
    - dill==0.2.7.1
    - h5py==2.10.0
    - idna==2.9
    - jieba==0.42.1
    - kytea==0.1.5
    - pythainlp==2.1.4
    - pyyaml==5.3.1
    - requests==2.23.0
    - sacremoses==0.0.41
    - scikit-learn==0.24.2
    - sentencepiece==0.1.96
    - seqeval==0.0.12
    - tinydb==3.15.2
    - urllib3==1.25.8
prefix: ~/.conda/envs/torch1.4
```

I would really appreciate it if you could let me know how to solve it.
Attempt to run code from VScode to remote server.
.....
.....
.....
......
.....
.....
......
.....
.....
.....
......
.....
.....
......
.....
.....
.....
......
.....
.....
......
.....
.....
.....
......
.....
.....
......
.....
.....
.....
......
.....
.....
......

Comment: Can you share the complete yml file?

Comment: I add the code. thak you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they are builds from the `fastchan` channel. Try adding that to the YAML file.

Note that `anaconda` is a subset of `defaults` - you don't need to list both.